# PowerShell Object in Object

Tags: powershell, object, formatting

I have the following code:

```
$Car = [PSCustomObject] @{
    Tire          = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Color = "Black"
        Count = 4
    }

    SteeringWheel = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Color   = "Blue"
        Buttons = 15
    }
}
```

Now I want to output the object using the Format-List cmdlet. This leads to the following edition:

```
Tire          : @{Color=Black; Count=4}
SteeringWheel : @{Color=Blue; Buttons=15}
```

I would like to have the output as follows:

```
Tire:
    Color:      Black
    Count:      4
SteeringWheel:
    Color:      Blue
    Buttons:    15
```

The output should be dynamic. I don't want to have to manually access the individual attributes as in the following example:

```
$Car.Tire
$Car.SteeringWheel
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`System.Management.Automation.PSObject.Members`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.members?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_PSObject_Members) to extract the members from the [`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0). Then we can use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) to filter out members that have the [`System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo.MemberType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfo.membertype?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_PSMemberInfo_MemberType) property equal to `NoteProperty`.

```
$Car = [PSCustomObject] @{
    Tire = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Color = "Black"
        Count = 4
    }
    SteeringWheel = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Color   = "Blue"
        Buttons = 15
    }
}

foreach ($object in $Car) {
    $members = $object.PSObject.Members | 
        Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}

    foreach ($member in $members) {
        "$($member.Name):"

        $values = $member.Value.PSObject.Members | 
            Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}

        foreach ($value in $values) {
            "`t$($value.Name):$($value.Value)"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tire:
    Color:Black
    Count:4
SteeringWheel:
    Color:Blue
    Buttons:15
```